# Docker compose ssl error on mac El Capitan

Tags: docker, docker-compose, osx-elcapitan

I get the following error when running docker compose on mac El Capitan. Anyone knows how to fix it? I suspect it is a problem with EL Capitan, but have no idea how to fix...

> SSL error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure (_ssl.c:581)

PS: I have tried the solution proposed here but it does not work: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1880

> echo $CURL_CA_BUNDLE 
>   unset CURL_CA_BUNDLE

Comment: Maybe this thread contains something useful? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/890

Answer (score -1):

It works now after I downgraded docker toolbox to **1.8.3** and docker-compose version is as follows

```
docker-compose version: 1.4.2
docker-py version: 1.3.1
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
```